# JQuery scrolling to html element always to top, zerro top coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to scroll to the element. 
I use this:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#rakenduse').offset().top}, 2000);
```

But the scroll is always top 0.
Console log :

```
console.log( $('#rakenduse').offset() );
```

Return : {top: 0, left: 0}
[But real position element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1hxU.jpg)

Comment: try adding `px` : $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#rakenduse').offset().top + 'px'}, 2000);

Comment: try adding px IS NOT WORK :  `$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#rakenduse').offset().top+'px'
            }, 2000);`

Comment: Can you show us the full block of code that you are using for this - e.g. is this in a function or a handler?

Comment: `$('#button').click(function(){
  $('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: $('#rakenduse').offset().top+'px'
 }, 2000);
 
 console.log($('#rakenduse').offset());
});`